# Are programming question on topic?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask question regarding are to write programs that interact with Tor?

Can we ask question regarding the library that exist to write program that interact with Tor?

Comment: If we agree on yes on that question, I suggest adding a tag programming.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, definitely! as long as it's Tor related.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and yes

I think tor.stackexchange.com should be the right to developer to find what tools exist in their language.  Question asking for list of tool and library specific to tor should be welcome.  Question asking for simple hello world like should be welcome.

Question asking for tool and library not related to tor should be off topic.

Question about complex programming issue should be off topic, people should be redirected to stack overflow.

---

If a programmer search for a programming language, he should have relevant information to start coding quality tor applications as quickly as possible.  If we do not allow those question, the programmer will come to site, search and from the result deduce that the tool for tor are not mature in his programming language.

Answer (score 0):

What do you all think about things like this question:

- [How to connect to a remote socket through tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-socket-through-tor)

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Tor other than they've added the caveat that all traffic will be going through Tor. However, the question itself is just a Python / sockets question that could easily be asked without the Tor caveat on SO. Several of the programming questions we've seen so far have seemed this way to me.

Maybe we should build a list of good/bad programming questions to give us some idea of what's on topic, and what's not. Things like "how do I implement part X of the path spec with a stack?" seem reasonable to me, things like "How do I proxy a connection... oh, and it's going to be going through Tor" seem like they'd get better results on SO. Thoughts?